# How to open a LinkedIn profile in the LinkedIn app on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, win-universal-app, linkedin-api, windows-10-mobile

On Android and iOS I can launch the LinkedIn app to a particular profile with a url as follows:

```
"https://linkedin.com/in/" + id
```

This doesn't seem to work on Windows Phone and results in the prompt to search the app store.  LinkedIn is installed on the device and logged in.  I can find no documentation.  Is there another uri scheme?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try open app protocol link, like this:

```
linkedin://#profile/168827189
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have had no luck with this route either.  Always just the prompt to search the Store.